# Java: Counting frequency of a sequence in a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, count

I'm writing a simple program that counts how many times a sequence appears in a string.

Case 1:

Given string: EATNEATMMMMEAT

Given sequence: EAT

The program should return a value of 3.

Case 2:

Given string: EATEAT

Given sequence: EAT

The program should return 2.

```
import java.util.*;
public class FrequencyOfSequence { //Finds the frequency of a sequence in a string s
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        String sequence = in.nextLine();
        String[] cArr = s.split(sequence);

        System.out.println(cArr.length); 

    }
}
```

My program works in case 1. It fails on the 2nd case because `s.split(sequence)` removes both 'EAT', leaving an array of size 0.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Don't use String#split and simply parse the String yourself in a loop.

Comment: a good ol' indexOf loop

Comment: What about overlapping matches? For example, if you search for "EE" in "EEE", is that 2 or 3?

Comment: @shmosel it's 1

Comment: Oops, I meant 1 or 2.

Answer (score 4):

Use Regex for this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sequence);
Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

int count = 0;
while (matcher.find())
    count++;

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: This works. But is a solution similar to mine possible?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `replace()` to remove the matches and calculate the difference in size:

```
int count = (s.length() - s.replace(sequence, "").length()) / sequence.length();
```

If you want to use the `split()` method, it should work if you use it like this:

```
int count = s.split(sequence, -1).length - 1;
```

The `-1` argument tells the method not to discard trailing empty strings. Then we subtract 1 from the length to avoid the fencepost problem.

Comment: I don't get it. Doing this on EATEAT returns 6.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more option you would like to try

```
     int count=0;
if(s.endsWith(sequence)){
     count=s.split(sequence).length;}
else{
  count=s.split(sequence).length-1;
}
```